# Doubt in showing that exterior algebra is graded

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Suppose that $M$ is an $R$-module. Then the exterior algebra is defined as the quotient

$$\wedge(M)=\frac{T(M)}{A(M)}$$
where $T(M)$ is the tensor algebra(which is a graded $R$-algebra) and $A(M)$ is the ideal of $T(M)$ generated by the elements of the form $\{m \otimes m : m \in M \}$.

Since $T(M)$ is graded $R$ algebra and $A(M) $ is a homogenous ideal of $T(M)$, then $\wedge(M)$ is graded algebra with the grading
$$\wedge(M)= \oplus_{k \geq 0 } \wedge^k(M) $$

Where $\wedge^k(M)=A(M) \cap T^k(M)$.  Thus $\wedge^0(M)= A(M) \cap T^0(M)=A(M) \cap R$ . We expect that $\wedge^0(M)=A(M) \cap R=R$ but

> I am unable to understand why $R \subset A(M)$?.

> And simmilarly why $T^1(M)=M \subset A(M)$

Comment: Where did you get $\wedge^k(M) = A(M) \cap T^k(M)$? That can't be right, because that would mean $\wedge(M) \subseteq A(M)$, but $\wedge(M)$ is a *quotient* by $A(M)$, not a subset of $A(M)$.

Comment: @DanielHast, Yes I read the definition but somehow messed up. Thanks for pointing out.